# Computing folder size: Empty folders have a default size?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to compute a folder's size in Python, but I have strange result.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
def bestsize(filepath):
    """ Return a tuple with 3 values. The first is the file (or folder size). The second and third
    have sense only for folder and are the number of files and subdirectories in folder
    """
    from os.path import getsize, isdir
    if not(isdir(filepath)): return (getsize(filepath), 1, 0)
    else:
        lf = []
        ld = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filepath):
            for name in files: lf.append(os.path.join(root, name))
            for dir in dirs: ld.append(os.path.join(root, dir))
        return (sum(getsize(i) for i in lf), len(lf), len(ld))
```

I have made some tests on it comparing result as said by Windows's Explorer.

I have created a folder named "temp", and in it is a subfolder called temp and a file of 7 bytes called `ciao.txt`. The temp folder is empty. 
If I execute my function I obtain that my main folder is 7 bytes in size. But with Windows Explorer I obtain 4096 bytes.

Must I compute a default size for all, also empty, subfolders?

The default function `getsize` in the os module returns 0 for all directories.

Edit: I have tested my code on a NTFS file system partition

Edit: Thanks, now I have understood. 
What I would like to do is a better dir/ls command. I use the former sum computed using getsize, now that I have understood the difference it is fine for me.

Edit2: I have edited the code putting my last version.

Comment: What's the filesystem? FAT32? NTFS?

Comment: The "empty folders" bit seems like a red herring to your actual question. Yes, empty folders have a default size—or, rather, a minimum size (if you fill and then empty out a directory, it may be larger). But that's 0 on Windows. (It's on the order of 32-128 on most Unix systems—if you ask for it, a directory has to have a real directory list, with `.` and `..` entries. While the filesystem _could_ create these lazily, that's not what HFS+, ext3, etc. do.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different ways to count the size of a file.

You can count the number of bytes actually used by the file.

Alternatively, you can count the number of bytes reserved for the file. Since you have to use whole blocks at a time, if your disk block size is 4096 bytes, even the smallest file uses up 4096 bytes that no other file can use (unless you're using the compressed filesystem option that nobody uses anymore).

Windows Explorer is showing the latter as "Size on Disk". You're calculating the former with `getsize`.

---

So, what if you want the actual size on disk?

On up-to-date Unix and Unix-like platforms, `os.stat` will include an `st_blocks`, and Python will show it to you. You can multiply that by the block size of the filesystem to get the right answer. But Windows doesn't have that.

As a quick hack, you can just round up to the nearest block size. There are some uncommon cases where this will give you the wrong answer (e.g., if you use NTFS multiple-stream files, you'd have to round up each stream's size, not the total), but usually this is good enough.

Finally, you can skip `os.stat` and go right to [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (via `ctypes` or `win32api`), or the older functions it replaced, to get the `FILE_STANDARD_INFO`. The `AllocationSize` is the "size on disk", and the `EndOfFile` is, for normal files, the "size".

Comment: Update for 2023: st_blocks is the number of 512-byte blocks. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result

Answer (score 1):

Explorer shows both "Size" and "Size on disk". Since multiple files cannot share disk clusters, the minimum size a file will occupy on disk is one cluster (4096 bytes on your machine). Look at "Size" in Explorer.